# Tridion tracking link not resolving, redirecting to error page

Tags: audience-manager, tracking

I am running into an issue with tracking+redirecting links opened in an email sent via Outbound Email. The tracking link looks like this:

```
https://.../outboundemail/Tracking/?a=L&p=$5vdNbzUvsknlTVoC-kAsbSJELY_wvHJA-Zxtvh5zWcV8X_vwKPkMID_fB8EHQeYBG5Np5LD9xPVa_czNUBGndAwcV2zfEkwdW9Ka7BOaV-7ArVnnLBZ83z$$
```

The route `/outboundemail/Tracking` maps to an MVC controller action, which only contains the following code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request);
Response.Redirect(handler.Url);
```

where Handler is from `Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Tracking`.
The handler URL always is a redirect to the error page URL, as it is configured in the `cd_audiencemanager_conf.xm`l element `/Redirect/GeneralError`.

My questions are:

- to how best troubleshoot this, which log files to look into
- wanting to understand how the Tridion handler uses the value of the p-parameter to determine a URL. Is there synching going on under the hood from CM->CD side, is the URL in a CD DB somewhere?

Comment: Additionally, I also see that, even though I have a /Redirect/GeneralError element in the config file containing Error.html, the handler Url is always /Redirect/GeneralError, so it is not actually using the value in case of an error.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide additional information, you should NOT use the comments for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is valid and points to an absolute URL. So there's no link resolving needed and it should just be redirected directly.

So most likely you are getting an error that isn't related to the actual handling, but something else (such as not being able to load the configuration file).

To find the error, look in the log file configured for either your website (if using in-process) or the Audience Manager micro-service (if you are using that).

As for how it uses the value of the "p" parameter, it's using a simple encryption mechanism to store the values that it needs in one parameter. So the data is all there, just obfuscated.

Comment: Thanks Peter, after deploying our latest release which contains an complete/updated cd_audiencemanager_conf.xml, it is working now.

Comment: Glad it was fixed! Perhaps you'd like to accept my answer, so others who might have the same or similar issues can see what worked for you? :)